# How can I determine what server an agent is executing on -- not a scheduled agent

Tags: lotus-domino, lotusscript

I need to capture which server an agent is running on.  When the agent is a scheduled agent, I can use property NotesAgent.ServerName.  But when the agent is executed from a url, 'ServerName' is blank.  Is it possible to get the server name?

Answer (score 1):

Found it: NotesSession.CurrentDatabase.Server

clem

Answer (score 0):

You can access the Server property of the NotesDatabase class, like this:

```
Dim session As New NotesSession
Dim db As NotesDatabase
Dim ag As NotesAgent

Set db = session.Currentdatabase
Set ag = session.Currentagent
If ag.Iswebagent then
    MsgBox db.server
End if
```